# String to Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have created a method that allows me to find the next empty Box:

```
public int CheckBox(int boxNum) {
        int BoxNumber = 0;

        TextBox[] itemBoxArray = new TextBox[] { itemBox0, itemBox1, itemBox2, itemBox3, itemBox4, itemBox5, itemBox6, itemBox7,
            itemBox8, itemBox9,itemBox10,itemBox11,itemBox12,itemBox13,itemBox14,itemBox15,};
        for (int i = 0; i < itemBoxArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemBoxArray[i].Text))
            {
                BoxNumber = i;
                i = 15;                    
            }
        }
        return BoxNumber;
    }
```

Next i created a button to check what the empty box is and i would like to input something into this box but i cannot find a way ro convert the string that carries the empty box number to that text box:

```
    private void StandAroundRebar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int emptybox = CheckBox(0);
        string emptyboxString = emptybox.ToString();

        string newbox = "itemBox" + emptyboxString;

        MessageBox.Show("TextBox # " + newbox + " is empty ");

        var textbox = this.Controls.Find(newbox, true); 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I would rather change the CheckBox method

```
public TextBox CheckBox() {   
        var itemBoxArray = new TextBox[] { itemBox0, itemBox1, itemBox2, itemBox3, itemBox4, itemBox5, itemBox6, itemBox7,
            itemBox8, itemBox9,itemBox10,itemBox11,itemBox12,itemBox13,itemBox14,itemBox15,};
        return itemBoxArray.First(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Text));//or  FirstOrDefault
    }
```

now you would get a TextBox returned, and could do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Excellent +1.  You could also query the form for all the textboxes.  `this.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` and not have to build the array.

Comment: Yes, if you want all the textboxes, which is not clear in question.

Answer (score 1):

You need this function:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will find it, all you have to do is casting it.
Then:

```
BoxNumber = i;
i = 15;
```

What should that do? You set the i to the box number and then you set it again to 15?!
That isn't supposed to work.

Comment: It is to break the loop I believe.

Comment: I don't know what this is supposed to do, I just know, it is nosense :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return the `TextBox` object directly?

```
public TextBox GetNextEmptyTextBox()
{
    return (new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 })
        .FirstOrDefault(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) and than a cast to TextBox.

```
TextBox newBox = this.Controls.Find("itemBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
```

Once you find your Box you can set the text:

```
newBox.Text = "my text";
```